# How to work with analog signal use to control sensorless BLDC motor?

Tags: stm32, brushless-dc-motor

I am study for the analog signal use to control BLDC motor and I have developed in program in STM32. This method is used to control BLDC motor proper document don't give any other website. So can you any others working in this method. Please help how can I develop program for using analog signal to control BLDC motor and related documents in this method share me?

Comment: There is also this which covers a few ways to do it: http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/T.pdf

Comment: This one has a little more focus on the BEMF sampling: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00020086-sensorless-bldc-motor-control-and-bemf-sampling-methods-with--st7mc-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: The analog signal you are talking about is called the Back-EMF (BEMF). If the two documents above are not enough you can find more by searching "sensorless BLDC" with the name of any microcontroller manufacturer. They all have white notes on how to do this. You do not want anything that talks about field-oriented control (FOC). You just want simple 6-step trapezoidal commutation.